# The tray icon cannot be displayed when the Ubuntu 20.10 is turned on

Tags: nvidia, gnome, system-tray

My system version is 20.10. I upgraded from 20.04. I found such a problem, the tray icon cannot be displayed when the system is turned on or restarted, but if I kiil the process and restart it, it will be fine.

I searched on Google and didn't see a similar problem.

[image: bug info]

This is my hardware configuration:

- CPU: Two Zhiqiang Intel® Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz × 56
- GPU: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [P106-100] / NVIDIA Corporation GP106
  [GeForce 1060]